# How to receive an image in telegram using python?

Tags: python, image-processing, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a translator bot that would translate from images. I've already got image to text and translation figured out for working with a file, but I can't really make it work with an image sent to bot in Telegram.

After reading documentation I thought that this would work:

```
chat_id = message.chat.id
    photo = message.photo[-1].file_id
    
    new_file = await bot.get_file(photo)
    new_file.download_to_drive()
```

But await doesn't seem to work here.
Other things I've tried were

```
updater = Updater(BOT_TOKEN, use_context = True)
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.PHOTO, handle_photo))
```

to try and filter messages with photos in them but dispatcher got removed in latest update of Telegram API so I don't really know how handle this now.

I'm not sure if this would help answer the question, but I use pytesseract for image to text in my code like this:
`text = pytesseract.image_to_string('img\\test2.png', config='-l jpn')`

Whole code is as follows:

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract
import os
import telebot
import asyncio
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
import io
from telegram.ext import *
from googletrans import Translator

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

BOT_TOKEN = os.environ.get('BOT_TOKEN')

bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\tesseract\\tesseract.exe'

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'hello'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Welcome")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['translate'])
def translate1(message):
    text = "Send a picture you want to translate"
    sent_msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, parse_mode="Markdown")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent_msg, translate2)

def translate2(message):
    coro = translate(message)
    asyncio.run(coro)

async def download(photo):
    new_file = await bot.get_file(photo)
    await new_file.download_to_drive()

async def translate(message):
    
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    photo = message.photo[-1].file_id
    
    new_file = await bot.get_file(photo)
    new_file.download_to_drive()
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get().content))
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='-l jpn')
    
    translator = Translator()
    translated_text = translator.translate(text, dest='uk' )
    
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=translated_text)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it myself, so I'll post the answer in case someone runs into the same problem.

The whole code would be:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
import re

from typing import Final

from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\tesseract\\tesseract.exe'

print('Starting up bot...')

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

TOKEN: Final = os.environ.get('BOT_TOKEN')

async def start_command(update: Update, context:ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text("Hello!")

async def error(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    print(f'Update {update} caused error {context.error}')

async def downloader(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    # Download file
    new_file = await update.message.effective_attachment[-1].get_file()
    file = await new_file.download_to_drive()
    
    return file

async def translate_msg(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    if (
            not update.message
            or not update.effective_chat
            or (
                not update.message.photo
                and not update.message.video
                and not update.message.document
                and not update.message.sticker
                and not update.message.animation
            )
        ):
            return
    file = await downloader(update, context)
   
    if not file:
        await update.message.reply_text("Something went wrong, try again")
        return
    
    image = Image.open(file)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='-l jpn')
    
    new_text = re.sub(r"[\n\r]+", " ", text)
    
    translated_text = GoogleTranslator(source='ja', target='uk').translate(new_text)
    await update.message.reply_text(translated_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()    
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))    
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.PHOTO, translate_msg))    
    app.add_error_handler(error)
    app.run_polling(poll_interval=3)
```

So the way to download a photo is:

```
async def downloader(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    
    new_file = await update.message.effective_attachment[-1].get_file()
    file = await new_file.download_to_drive()
    
    return file
```

Quoting official documentation:

> async download_to_drive(custom_path=None, *, read_timeout=None,
> write_timeout=None, connect_timeout=None, pool_timeout=None)
>
> Download this file. By default, the file is saved in the current
> working directory with file_path as f ile name. If the file has no
> filename, the file ID will be used as filename. If custom_path is
> supplied as a str or pathlib.Path, it will be saved to that path.

> Changed in version 20.0:
>
> • custom_path parameter now also accepts pathlib.Path as argument.
>
> • Returns pathlib.Path object in cases where previously a str was returned.
>
> • This method was previously called download. It was split into download_to_drive() and download_to_memory().

It's also possible to use

> async download_to_memory(out, *, read_timeout=None,
> write_timeout=None, connect_timeout=None, pool_timeout=None)
>
> Download this file into memory. out needs to be supplied with a
> io.BufferedIOBase, the file contents will be saved to that object
> using the out.write method.

Effective attachment is:

> property effective_attachment If this message is neither a plain text
> message nor a status update, this gives the attachment that this
> message was sent with. This may be one of
>
> • telegram.Audio
>
> • telegram.Dice
>
> • telegram.Contact
>
> • telegram.Document
>
> • telegram.Animation
>
> • telegram.Game
>
> • telegram.Invoice
>
> • telegram.Location
>
> • telegram.PassportData
>
> • List[telegram.PhotoSize]
>
> • telegram.Poll
>
> • telegram.Sticker
>
> • telegram.SuccessfulPayment
>
> • telegram.Venue
>
> • telegram.Video
>
> • telegram.VideoNote
>
> • telegram.Voice Otherwise None is returned.

And get_file:

> async get_file(file_id, *, read_timeout=None, write_timeout=None,
> connect_timeout=None, pool_timeout=None, api_kwargs=None)
>
> Use this method to get basic info about a file and prepare it for
> downloading. For the moment, bots can download files of up to 20 MB in
> size. The file can then be e.g. downloaded with telegram.File.
> download_to_drive(). It is guaranteed that the link will be valid for
> at least 1 hour. When the link expires, a new one can be requested by
> calling get_file again.

Apart from that, I had to make a list of handlers and initialize bot as `Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()` instead of `telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)`.
So now commands are passed as (if `app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()`)

```
app.add_handler(CommandHandler('command_name_as_it_is_displayed_in_bot', function_that_should_be_called))
```

And non-command messages are passed as (if `app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()`)

```
app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.<filter here>, function_that_should_be_called))
```